# How can I format contentSize in Content Navigator search results?

Tags: java, ibm-content-navigator

I'm writing a Content Navigator response filter that will format two fields in a search result:

- A date field

  EXAMPLE: 2018-04-03T00:00:00 -> 04-03-2018
- The content size field:

  EXAMPLE: 14859 -> 14.5 kB

The "date" field was no problem - it worked fine.

The "content size" field isn't working. No errors or warnings - ICN just isn't displaying the formatted value.

The problem *might* be that ICN declares 'contentSize' to be `xs:long`  ... and a "long" column can't contain letters like "kB", or punctuation like "."

Here's my code:

```
    private void filterSearch(JSONResultSetResponse jsonResultSetResponse) throws Exception {
        // For each document returned by the search...
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResultSetResponse.getRowCount(); i++) {
            JSONResultSetRow row = jsonResultSetResponse.getRow(i);
            ...
            // contentSize
            Long size = Long.parseLong((String)currentValue);
            final String[] units = new String[] { "", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
            int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size)/Math.log10(1024));
            String formattedSize = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size/Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];

            // EXAMPLE: change 14859 -> 14.5 kB
            row.setAttributeType(symName, "xs:string");
            row.setAttributeValue(symName, formattedSize);
            ...
```

Q: Any ideas how I can correctly format a "long" value in Content Navigator search results?

Comment: use double type for your file size

Answer (score 0):

Use this, set format as "fileSize".

```
row.addAttribute(title, (Double)value, JSONResultSetRow.TYPE_INTEGER, "fileSize", null);
```